# SharePoint: What's the relationship between site columns, content types and lists

Tags: sharepoint

First time touch SharePoint, still confused what's site columns, Content types and lists and what are the relationships.

Can anyone give me an example pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, I will compare the list with a database table or an Excel table.

> List

For List,it likes a database table or an Excel table.
It is a list, a collection of information. There are some rows(data) and columns(define type);

> Site Columns

I will compare it to a field in a database table or a column,not data in an Excel table.
e.g. you can use query to get a collection of few columns of data.

> Content Type

The content type is equivalent to defining some metadata. It can be considered that combining some columns or some site columns becomes a content type, or it can be understand as defining a data organization form, like defining a class.

Answer (score 1):

> Site Columns:-

A site column represents a type of data.Site Columns define reusable column definitions and Content Types, which are made up of Site Columns, define reusable schema's for both lists and libraries.

> List

List is a collection of information in SharePoint that you can share with others. Lists consist of rows of columns that contain data Such as Mobile Number,Address,etc.

> Content Type

A content type defines the metadata, workflow, and behavior for a category of items in a SharePoint list or document library. A contact content type might include columns such as Name, Email, Telephone Number, and Address.

References:-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/creating-site-columns-content-types-and-lists-for-sharepoint

Comment: thanks for list out the definition. Do you have any diagram to show the relationship between these things?